# The linearization problem of fully nonlinear equation on standard sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

For a metric $g$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n}$ $(n\geq 3)$, the $\sigma_k$-curvature of $g$ is defined as follows. Let $Ric_{g}$, $R_{g}$ and $A_{g}$ denote respectively the Ricci curvature, the scalar curvature and the Schouten tensor of $g$:
\begin{equation*}
A_{g}=\frac{1}{n-2}\left(Ric_{g}-\frac{R_{g}}{2(n-1)}g\right).
\end{equation*}
Let $\lambda(A_g)$ denote the eigenvalues of $A_g$ with respect to $g$. For $1 \leq k \leq n$, the $\sigma_k$-curvature of $g$ is then the function $\sigma_k(\lambda(A_g))$ where $\sigma_k$ is the $k$-elementary symmetric function, $\sigma_k(\lambda)=\sum\limits_{i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k}}\lambda_{i_{1}}\cdots\lambda_{i_{k}}$. We want to find the  unknown metric $g$ which is conformal to the standard metric $g_0$, such that
\begin{align}\label{1}
\sigma_k(\lambda(A_{g})) = 1\quad  \text{ and } \lambda(A_{g}) \in \Gamma_k \text{ on }\,\mathbb{S}^{n},\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)
\end{align}
and $\Gamma_k$ is the connected component of $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sigma_k(\lambda) > 0\}$ which contains the positive cone $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n: \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n > 0\}$. (1) is also called the $\sigma_k$-Yamabe problem on $\mathbb{S}^n$.

Write the metric $g$ as $g_v =  v^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0$ for some positive function $v$. Note that
\begin{equation*}
A_{g_{v}}=A_{g_0}-\frac{2}{n-2}v^{-1}\nabla^{2}_{g_0}v+\frac{2n}{(n-2)^{2}}v^{-2}dv\otimes  d v-\frac{2}{(n-2)^{2}}v^{-2}|dv|^{2}_{g_0}g_0.
\end{equation*}
For $2 \leq k \leq n$,  we need to solve  a fully nonlinear elliptic equation for $v$.

Define the operator
$$
F_{\mu}[v]:=\sigma_{k}(\lambda(A_{g_{v}}))-1.
$$
and $$
\mathcal{S}_{0} =\Big\{v\in C^{4,\alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n):\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}x |v(x)|^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}\,dv_{g_0}(x) =0\Big\}.
$$
We parametrize $C^{4,\alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n)$ as $\mathcal{S}_0 \times \mathbb{R}$ where the $\mathbb{R}$-factor takes into account the the action of the M"obius group on $\mathbb{S}^n$ on axisymmetric functions and where the element $1 \in \mathcal{S}_0$ corresponds to the so-called axisymmetric standard bubbles on $\mathbb{S}^n$. To this end, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\varphi_{t}$ be the M"obius transformation on $\mathbb{S}^n$ which, under stereographic projection with respect to the north pole, sends $y$ to $ty$. For function $v$ defined on $\mathbb{S}^n$, we let
$$
T_{t}v:=v\circ\varphi_t|\det d\varphi_t|^{\frac{n-2}{2n}},
$$
where $d\varphi_t$ denotes the Jacobian of $\varphi_t$. In particular, the pull-back metric of $g_v = v^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0$ under $\varphi_t$ is given by $\varphi_t^* (g_v) = g_{T_t v}$.

The linearized operator of $F_\mu[\pi(\cdot,t)]$ at $\bar w \equiv 1$ is readily found to be
$$
\mathcal{L} := D_w (F_\mu \circ \pi)(w,\xi)]\Big|_{w = \bar w} = - d_{n,k}(\Delta + n) \quad \text{ with } \quad d_{n,k} := \frac{2^{2-k}}{n-2} \Big(\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\Big)
$$
and with domain $D(\mathcal{L})$ being the tangent plane to $\mathcal{S}_0$ at $w = \bar w$:
$$
D(\mathcal{L}) := T_1(\mathcal{S}_0) = \Big\{\eta \in C^{4,\alpha}(\mathbb{S}^n): \int_{\mathbb{S}^n} x \eta(x)\,dv_{g_0}(x) = 0\Big\}.
$$
I don't know how to obtain the expression of the  linearized operator of $F_\mu[\pi(\cdot,t)]$ at $\bar w \equiv 1$ since the fully nonlinear term $\sigma_k(\lambda(A_{g_v}))$  is very hard to calculate, I have no idea to check the above results $\mathcal{L}$. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my favorite way to do this computation.

Let
$$ \delta_{i_1 \dotsm i_k}^{j_1 \dotsm j_k} = \begin{cases} \mathrm{sgn}\, \sigma, & \text{if $j_k = i_{\sigma(k)}$}, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
be the [generalized Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Definitions_of_the_generalized_Kronecker_delta).
Then
$$ \sigma_k(\lambda(A)) = \frac{1}{k!}\delta_{i_1 \dotsm i_k}^{j_1 \dotsm j_k} A_{j_1}^{i_1} \dotsm A_{j_k}^{i_k} , $$
as can be checked, for example, by diagonalizing $A$.
It immediately follows that
$$ \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=0} \sigma_k(\lambda(A + tB)) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\delta_{i_1 \dotsm i_k}^{j_1 \dotsm j_k} B_{j_1}^{i_1} A_{j_2}^{i_2} \dotsm A_{j_k}^{i_k} . $$
It is also easy to check that on an $n$-dimensional vector space,
$$ \frac{1}{k!}\delta_{j_k}^{i_k}\delta_{i_1 \dotsm i_k}^{j_1 \dotsm j_k} = \frac{n-k+1}{k!}\delta_{i_1 \dotsm i_{k-1}}^{j_1 \dotsm j_{k-1}} . $$

Now let’s specialize to the sphere, where $A_{g_0} = \frac{1}{2}g_0$.
Using your equation for $A_{g_v}$ for $g_v = (1+tv)^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0$, we see that
$$ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} A_{g_{tv}} = -\frac{2}{n-2}\nabla^2v . $$
Therefore
$$ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} (A_{g_{tv}})_i^j = -\frac{2}{n-2}v_i^j - \frac{2}{n-2}v\delta_i^j $$
(Recall that you need to raise an index to define $\sigma_k$, hence the second summand.)
Putting everything together yields
\begin{align*}
 \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0} \sigma_k(\lambda(g_{tv})) & = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\delta_{i_1 \dotsm i_k}^{j_1 \dotsm j_k}\left( -\frac{2}{n-2}v_{j_1}^{i_1} - \frac{4}{n-2}v\delta_{j_1}^{i_1} \right)\left( \frac{1}{2}\delta_{j_2}^{i_2}\right) \dotsm \left( \frac{1}{2}\delta_{j_k}^{i_k} \right) \\
& = -\frac{2^{1+1-k}}{n-2}\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)\dotsm(n-k+k-1)}{(k-1)!}\delta_i^j\left(v_j^i + v\delta_j^i \right) \\
& = -\frac{2^{2-k}}{n-2}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(\Delta v + n) .
\end{align*}
I’m not entirely sure why your expression has an extra factor of $\frac{n}{k}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a question:  if the Shouten tensor $A_g$ can be calculated like a $n\times n$ matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$? I remember that  the eigenvalue of $A_g$ is defined by seeking the eigenvalues of $g^{-1}A_g$, I‘m not sure the expression $\sigma_k(\lambda(A))$ can be also applied.

Comment: The tensor $g^{-1}A_g$ is a section of $T^\ast M \otimes TM \cong \mathrm{End}(TM)$, so for each point $p \in M$, the value of $g^{-1}A_g$ is a linear map, and hence one can meaningfully talk about the eigenvalues (or think of it as an $n \times n$ matrix).  Without a metric, there is no way to talk about the eigenvalues of a section of $T^\ast M \otimes T^\ast M$.  This is what I meant by needing to raise an index to define $\sigma_k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way,  I have some confusion about the notations.  If $A^{i}_j$ denote the elements of the matrix $A$, and $v_i^j$ means the second derivative of $v$ like $\partial_i\partial_j v$?

Comment: $v_i^j$ denotes the components of the matrix $g_0^{-1}D^2v$, where $D^2v$ is the Hessian of $v$ with respect to the metric $g_0$.

Comment: I have  more questions about the linealization process: what about the effect $t$ in $\pi(w,t)$ when we condiser the  the linearized operator of $F_\mu[\pi(\cdot, t)]$ at $\bar{w} \equiv 1$, it seems that the result should contain the other variable $t$?  (just Intuitively) On the other hand, why we only need to consider the equation $\sigma_k(\lambda(A_{g_{tv}}))$ for $g_{tv}=(1+t v)^{\frac{4}{n-2}} g_0$  to obtain the result we wanted, I can not get the idea for such transformation. Thanks again!

Comment: For your second question: I computed the linearization $D_v\mathcal{F}_\mu(w)\rvert_{w=1}$.  To do this, you just need to pick an arbitrary path $w_t$ with $w_0=1$ and $\dot w=v$.  Mine is the straight line path with respect to your parameterization $g_w = w^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g$ of the conformal metric.  For the first question, the point is that $\varphi_t$ is a conformal diffeomorphism.  Its role is similar to the role of the Kelvin transform in the linked question.