# Kelvin transformation in fully nonlinear equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

Let $g_\text{flat}$ denote the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A^u$ denote the $(1,1)$-Schouten tensor of $u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_\text{flat}$,
$$
    A^u = -\frac{2}{n-2}u^{-\frac{n+2}{n-2}}\nabla^{2}u+\frac{2n}{(n-2)^2} u^{-\frac{2n}{n-2}}\nabla u\otimes  \nabla u - \frac{2}{(n-2)^2} u^{-\frac{2n}{n-2}}|\nabla u|^2 g_\text{flat}.$$

Consider the equation
$$  \sigma_k(\lambda(A^{u}))=K(x) \quad \text
{and}\quad \lambda(A^{ u}) \in \Gamma_k \text{ on } \, \mathbb{R}^n,$$where $\lambda(A^{ u})=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ denote the eigenvalues of $A^u$, $\sigma_k$ is the $k$-elementary symmetric function, i.e., $$\sigma_k(\lambda)=\sum\limits_{i_1 < \cdots < i_k} \lambda_{i_1} \cdots \lambda_{i_k},$$
and  $\Gamma_k$ is the connected component of $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sigma_k(\lambda) > 0\}$ which contains the positive cone $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n: \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n > 0\}$ (to ensure the equation is elliptic.) $K(x)$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let  $\hat{u}(z)=|z|^{2-n} u\left(\frac{z}{|z|^2}\right)$, is it true
$$\sigma_k(\lambda(A^{\hat{u}(z)}))=K\left(\frac{z}{|z|^2}\right) \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda(A^{ \hat{u}}) \in \Gamma_k \text{ on } \, \mathbb{R}^n?$$
This is well-known that $\hat{u}(z)$ is a Kelvin transformation of $u$, but seems not easy to check the above equation. Did I miss someting?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation. What is are the definitions of $\lambda$, $\sigma_k$, and $\Gamma_k$?

Comment: sorry! I will revise the question.

Comment: what is $\tilde{u}$? Is it just $u$?

Comment: Some typos, sorry!

Comment: Is $K$ a function or a constant? (Specifically, is $K(z/|z|^2)$ the function $K$ evaluated at the point $z/|z|^2$?)

Comment: Sorry!  $K$ is a function.

Comment: The checking is actually not too bad if you do it in spherical coordinates. Write $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ as the warped product $(0,\infty)\times_r \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, and denote by $\theta$ some spherical coordinate, then the only non-trivial term in the Hessian is $\nabla^2_{r\theta} = \partial_r \partial_\theta - \frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta$. The angular derivatives pass right through the $u\mapsto \hat{u}$ transform, this simplifies computations.

Comment: The point is that the transformation property is at the level of the Schouten tensor itself and holds pointwise, so if the Schouten tensor transforms appropriately, so must the eigenvalues and other matrix invariants.

Answer (score 2):

This follows easily from the fact that the Kelvin transform is a conformal diffeomorphism and the naturality of the Schouten tensor.

Let $\Phi(z) := \frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert^2}$ denote the Kelvin transform.
It is easy to check that $\Phi$ is a conformal diffeomorphism.
In fact,
$$ \Phi^\ast g_0 = \lvert z\rvert^{-4} g_0 . $$
(As suggested in the comments, this is very easy to check in spherical coordinates, where $g_0 = dr^2 + r^2g_{S^{n-1}}$.)
Therefore
$$ \Phi^\ast g_u = \Phi^\ast (u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0) = (u \circ \Phi)^{\frac{4}{n-2}}\lvert z\rvert^{-4} g_0 = \left( \lvert z\rvert^{2-n}(u\circ \Phi)\right)^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0 = \hat u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0 . $$

The naturality of the Schouten tensor is the statement $\Psi^\ast (A^g) = A^{\Psi^\ast g}$ for any diffeomorphism $\Psi$.
Therefore $\Psi^\ast (g^{-1}A^g) = (\Psi^\ast g)^{-1}A^{\Psi^\ast g}$ where, as usual, $g^{-1}$ is the musical operator that raises one index.

Finally, recall that $\sigma_k(\lambda(A^u)) = \sigma_k(g_u^{-1}A^u)$, as mentioned in [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/444973/121820) to your other question.
Combining the above gives
\begin{align*}
 K\left( \frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert^2} \right) & = (\Phi^\ast K)(z) \\
 & = \left( \Phi^\ast \sigma_k(g_u^{-1}A^{u}) \right)(z) \\
 & = \sigma_k(g_{\hat u}^{-1}A^{\hat u})(z) .
\end{align*}
Repeating this argument with different values of $k$ also shows that the positive cone is preserved by the Kelvin transform.

Comment: Thanks again! I want to ask here the notation $g_0$ is the Euclidean metric $g_{flat}$? By the way, if convenient,  would you recommend me some references that are friendly to read. Thank you very much.

Comment: Right, $g_0$ is the flat metric.  Without knowing your background and interests, I'm unsure of what would be a "friendly" reference.  A good starting point might be one of Alice Chang's survey articles on fully nonlinear elliptic equations.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question, the Kelvin transform make a dialation on the variable $z\rightarrow\frac{z}{|z|^2}$, however the origin $z=0$  that is not make sense  will not make any problem?

Comment: In general you don’t have an equation which makes sense at $z=0$.  There are some removable singularity theorems under appropriate assumptions on $u$ and $K$.  You can probably find details in papers by Yanyan Li or Maria del Mar Gonzalez from the early- to mid-2000s, but I don’t know the most general reference.